# ViewCompat.generateViewId() to a specific R.id name?

Tags: android, layout, resources

I have a custom view that inherits from `ConstraintLayout`

I want to set an Id for that layout named:

it inflates this xml:

```
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_display_name"
        style="@style/AccountDataDisplayName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="?attr/text_marginStart"
        android:layout_marginEnd="?attr/text_marginEnd"
        android:layout_marginLeft="?attr/text_marginLeft"
```

since there is only `<merge>` at the top most node,

how can I set an id to my customView?

I know i can use this:

```
 ViewCompat.generateViewId();
```

but I want to set it into a identifier named:

```
R.id.has_selected_account = ViewCompat.generateViewId();
this.setId(R.id.has_selected_account);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow you, but you could define that ID in your resources, anywhere under `res/values/` – `<item type="id" name="has_selected_account" />`. Rebuild, and you will then have `R.id.has_selected_account` available.

Comment: I did that. built. but i still get `error: cannot find symbol
    this.setId(R.id.has_selected_account);`

Comment: Clean/rebuild, maybe? Dunno. I just tested, and didn't even have to rebuild for it to recognize it.

Comment: OK, I misspoke slightly. You can't put it just anywhere. That `<item>` must be a direct child of the `<resources>` element in whatever particular file you put it in. It can't be inside anything else, like a `<declare-styleable>`. My bad.

Comment: use an `<include/>` tag to include the `<merge/>` layout to the main layout you want it to appear on. The system ignores the `<merge/>` element and places the `<TextView/>` directly in the layout, in place of the `<include/>` tag. I hope this helps you.

Comment: @MikeM. can you please write your last comment as an answer?